# detect distance scrolled from top jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I detect the number of pixels scrolled in a browser window? 
I need this to dynamically adjust the height of a 100% height div...

I'm using jQuery.

EDIT: I cannot just use scrollTop() because I'm working with a 100% height div with overflow set to auto. Firefox does not detect browser scrolling due to this, the only thing scrolling is a 100%x100% div...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Allright guys, I found it:

```
$("div#container").scroll(function() {
         var screenheight = parseInt($(document).height());
         var scrolledpx = parseInt($("div#container").scrollTop());     
         var sum = screenheight+scrolledpx;
         console.log($("div#container").scrollTop());
         console.log("screen: " + screenheight);
         console.log("sum=" + sum);
         $("div.content").height(sum);
})
```

Answer (score 86):

use `$(document).scrollTop()` :

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    console.log($(document).scrollTop());
})
```

Comment: thanks for you help, but I get nothing in my console. I'm using firefox 3.5.7. Seems like it's not responding to the event

Comment: in safari and chrome it's triggering the event, not in firefox or IE

Comment: I think I know what's wrong. I have a 100% height implemented with overflow set to auto. I guess it's not detecting a window scroll but a scroll in the overflowing div, can that be?

Comment: @Jorre: it sure can. Try replacing `document` with your div's selector.

Answer (score 9):

You can use scrollTop() to find out how far down the page you've traveled.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  console.log($(window).scrollTop());
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
    $('#div').stop().animate({
      'marginTop': $(window).scrollTop() + 'px',
      'marginLeft': $(window).scrollLeft() + 'px'
    }, 'slow');
  }
});
```

Comment: I had to modify the above script so that it would work with a scrolling DIV.  I had to code it as `parseInt($("#container").scrollTop())` so that the resulting value was able to be evaluated as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(()=> {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
  })
}
```