# How do I get the browser scroll position in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web document with scroll.  I want to get the value, in pixels, of the current scroll position.  When I run the below function it returns the value zero.  How can I do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function (){
        $('#Eframe').on("mousewheel", function() {
            alert(document.body.scrollDown)
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: You want to get the amount of pixels a user scrolled ? just the first time they scroll ? correct ?

Comment: This links will be usefull for you:-
http://papermashup.com/jquery-page-scrolling/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081064/how-to-get-the-num-of-pixels-a-user-has-scrolled-down-the-page
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148310/jquery-if-scroll-is-a-certain-amount-of-pixels


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021440/detect-distance-scrolled-from-top-jquery

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Since it appears you are using jQuery, here is a jQuery solution.

```
$(function() {
    $('#Eframe').on("mousewheel", function() {
        alert($(document).scrollTop());
    });
});
```

Not much to explain here.  If you want, here is [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/).

Comment: This just gives me 0 the whole time

Comment: @Pomster @r3wt You have to make sure you set the function to whatever document object is scrolling. So if the scroll is on some `<div id="foo">...`, the syntax would be `$("#foo").scrollTop()`.

Answer (score 35):

It's better to use `$(window).scroll()` rather than `$('#Eframe').on("mousewheel")`

`$('#Eframe').on("mousewheel")` will not trigger if people manually scroll using up and down arrows on the scroll bar or grabbing and dragging the scroll bar itself.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    console.log(scrollPos);
});
```

If `#Eframe` is an element with `overflow:scroll` on it and you want it's scroll position. I think this should work (I haven't tested it though).

```
$('#Eframe').scroll(function(){
    var scrollPos = $('#Eframe').scrollTop();
    console.log(scrollPos);
});
```

Comment: This should be the chosen answer

Answer (score 12):

Pure javascript can do!

```
var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
```

Comment: in my case `scrollTop` gives me scroll done by the browser after page refresh, which exactly what I wanted